# Proving one limit is equal to another

Tags: real-analysis

Let ($x_s$) be a convergent sequence, where $x_s>0$ for all s, and $y_s$ be a sequence such that

$$\displaystyle \Large y_s=\frac{s}{\frac{1}{x_1}+...+\frac{1}{x_s}}$$

Prove $\displaystyle \lim x_s$=$\lim y_s$

So I know things like $x_s$ is bounded, and that it's Cauchy, but I can't think of anything to solve it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence $(x_{s})_{s \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to some $\ell > 0$ then :

The Cesaro theorem states that, since the sequence $\displaystyle \Big( \frac{1}{x_s} \Big)_{s \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ell}$, we have :

$$ \frac{1}{s} \sum_{k=1}^{s} \frac{1}{x_k} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{s \to +\infty} \, \frac{1}{\ell}. $$

As a consequence,

$$ y_{s} = \Big( \frac{1}{s} \sum_{k=1}^{s} \frac{1}{x_k} \Big)^{-1} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{s \to +\infty} \, \ell = \lim \limits_{s \to +\infty} x_{s}. $$

If the sequence $(x_s)_{s \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$, the sequence $\displaystyle \Big( \frac{1}{x_s} \Big)_{s \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $+\infty$ and Cesaro again allows us to state that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{s} \sum_{k=1}^{s} \frac{1}{x_k} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{s \to +\infty} \, +\infty$. Therefore : $y_{s} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{s \to +\infty} 0$.

Comment: $l$ need not be strictly greater than $0$ though. it's not a big problem, but thought it was worth pointing out

Comment: @mm-aops : You're right, I'll edit my post !

Comment: This is beautiful, my only issue is I don't follow the Cesaro part because I never learnt what that was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume first that the limit of $x_n$ is different from $0$. What is the limit of $\frac{1}{x_n}$ then? Combine it with the fact that if $a_n$ converges to $a$ then $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n a_k \rightarrow a$$
as well. Then just use the first trick - deducing the limit of $1/x_n$ from the limit of $x_n$ and you're done. A similar argument will work for $x_n$ converging to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $a_{n}$ converges to $a$ and $\overline{a}_{n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$
then also $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{a}_{n}=a$.